# Database file does not get recreated after I delete mdf file

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using MVC, ASP.NET with Entity Framework and MS SQL CE. First time I hit F5 and build the MDF files gets created. I added some test data, works fine.

Then I decide to write a Seed method to populate with some data. Get a clean database. So I try to delete the mdf file but ohh that is bad. It does not work.

How can I nuke the old mdf file and recreate it?

Comment: Is it really SQL CE? SQL Compact uses `.sdf` files. `.mdf` is used by LocalDB and all other SQL Server editions.

Comment: I got this line in my web config.   <add name="CarSales" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|CarSales.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" /> Why the database is created as an mdf file, I dont know

Comment: Perhaps check the constructor of your `DbContext`, is there no other connectionString in your config file?